# Is there a way to pass a php variable to another page using a button (html/php)?

Tags: php, html

For example, say you have a loop that produces a button every time it loops. So if the loop ran five times, there would be 5 buttons. Now say i have a variable like $num which will change each time the loop loops. Is there a way so that each button will pass its individual $num when the button is clicked?

```
$num = 0;
while(...){
    //want this to send $num via POST or GET to xyz.php
    echo '<button type="submit" value="3" name="editId">Remove</button>';
    $num++;//$num changes every instance of the loop
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to create a `<form>` surrounding each of the `<button>` tags:

```
$num = 0;
while(...){
    //want this to send $num via POST or GET to xyz.php
    echo '<form method="post" action="xyz.php">';
    // Pass $num into the form value
    echo '<button type="submit" value="' . $num. '" name="editId">Remove</button>';
    echo '</form>'
    $num++;
}
```

Whichever is clicked will be passed to `xyz.php` as `$_POST['editId']`.

While this method creates a different form for each button, there are other ways to do it using JavaScript which would use a single form and assign the value to a hidden input based on the button clicked.  If it's only the one input value being sent, the multiple `<form>`s option is probably easiest to code.

Comment: The problem with doing this is that you'd end up with 5 (or more) `<form>` tags which are unnecessary.

Comment: Multiple forms are unnecessary. The forms with multiple `button` elements will pass the name / value of whatever button was pressed to submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

The button's name & value should be submitted with the form.

For example:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="button" value="value">Button</button>
</form>
```

When the button "Button" is clicked, the form will be submitted and

```
Array ( [button] => value )
```

Will be output above the form.

Applying this to your situation, one could use something like:

```
$num = 0;
while(...){
    // Set $num as the value of each button
    echo "<button type='submit' value='{$num}' name='editId'>Remove</button>";
    $num++;//$num changes every instance of the loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there:

```
$num = 0; while(...){     //want this to send $num via POST or GET to xyz.php  
echo '<button type="submit" value="'.$num.'" name="editId">Remove</button>';     
$num++;//$num changes every instance of the loop 
}
```

Comment: @highway of life, now that's funny. For a second I thought you copy/pasted my answer. :) Guess you actually answered first. And I think we both assumed the OP was putting these in a <form>

Comment: LOL!! That's very funny... I thought for a moment my answer got posted twice somehow, since we both used the same format for concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. Just insert `$num` into the `value` attribute of your button.

```php
$num = 0;
while(...){
    //want this to send $num via POST or GET to xyz.php
    echo '<button type="submit" value="'.$num.'" name="editId">Remove</button>';
    $num++;//$num changes every instance of the loop
}
```

When you surround this code block in `<form>` tags, clicking the `[ Remove ]` button would send the value of `$num` to: `$_POST['editId']`.